# Parse #Hashtag Comments From SQL Server Record

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014, hashtag

I am trying to pull all "#" comments from a text field in a SQL Server 2014 database.  I am using the code I found on this [MSDN thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/315c7039-8064-4412-8a5d-eeeb64fd54f9/finding-multiple-hashtags-in-one-record?forum=transactsql) to find multiple hashtags in one record and have modified it slightly to fit my needs, but I seeing some unexpected results in my result set.

My T-SQL so far:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#hashtag') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #hashtag;

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#numbers') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #numbers;

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#hashtagcounts') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #hashtagcounts;

CREATE TABLE #numbers ( N INT );
DECLARE @i INT; 
SET @i = 1;
WHILE @i < 500
BEGIN
    INSERT  #numbers
    VALUES  ( @i );
    SET @i = @i + 1;
END;

CREATE TABLE #hashtag ( tkt_desc VARCHAR(MAX) );

INSERT INTO #hashtag ( tkt_desc )
SELECT  cst.ticketDescription
FROM    dbo.Trending AS [cst]
    WHERE   cst.ticketDescription LIKE '%#%'
            AND LTRIM(RTRIM(cst.ticketDescription)) NOT LIKE '%# %'
            AND cst.ticketDescription NOT LIKE '%BATCH #%'
            AND cst.ticketDescription NOT LIKE '%#[.:''1-9]%';

SELECT  LOWER ('#' + SUBSTRING(tkt_desc, N,
              CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(' ', tkt_desc, N) > 0
                   THEN CHARINDEX(' ', tkt_desc, N) - N
                   ELSE LEN(tkt_desc)
              END)) AS tkt_desc
INTO #hashtagcounts
FROM    #hashtag
    CROSS JOIN #numbers
WHERE   N <= LEN(tkt_desc) AND SUBSTRING(tkt_desc, N - 1, 1) = '#';

SELECT tkt_desc, COUNT(*) AS [Count]
FROM #hashtagcounts
GROUP BY tkt_desc
ORDER BY Count DESC, tkt_desc;
```

And my data set look like:

```
tkt_desc              Count
#updateinfo           6
#update               4
#update update        3
#update updated       3
#reprint              2
#callback             1
#nochargereprint      1
#nocostreprint        1
#notes update         1
#paperlicense please  1
```

I am experiencing issues where the #update tag is represented three different ways. Ideally, I would like not include anything that come after a blank space ' ' in the hashtag - and the #update tag should see a count of 10.

My initial thought was that since this is a text field, there may be line break or carriage return in the field, so I tried to handle this by replacing `SELECT cst.ticketDescription` with `REPLACE(REPLACE(cst.ticketDescription,CHAR(13),''),CHAR(10),'')` but that simply combines the separate words into one hashtag.  See example below:

```
#updateinfo    6
#update        4
#updateupdate  3
#updateupdated 3
```

Any suggestions on how I might achieve my desired result?  And I am including some sample data below in case anyone would like to experiment.

Query that I decided on using the two Functions / Cross Apply and cleaned up the LIKE and NOT LIKE statements:

```
SELECT  '#' + LOWER(B.RetVal) AS [HashTag] ,
    COUNT(*) AS [Cnt]
FROM    dbo.Common_SupportTickets AS [cst]
    CROSS APPLY [dbo].[udf-Str-Extract]([dbo].[udf-Str-Strip-Control](cst.ticketDescription) + ' ', '#', ' ') AS [B]
WHERE   cst.ticketDescription LIKE '%#%'
    AND LTRIM(RTRIM(REPLACE(cst.ticketDescription,CHAR(13)+CHAR(10),''))) NOT LIKE '%#'
    AND cst.ticketDescription NOT LIKE '%BATCH #%'
    AND cst.ticketDescription NOT LIKE '%#[.:'')1-9]%'
    AND CAST(cst.createDate AS DATE) >= CAST( @paramStartDate AS DATE )
    AND CAST(cst.createDate AS DATE) <= CAST( @paramEndDate AS DATE )
GROUP BY B.RetVal
```

Sample data and records:

```
USE [Sandbox]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Trending](
[TicketDescription] [varchar](max) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]

GO
INSERT [dbo].[Trending] ([TicketDescription]) VALUES (N'#registrationnotreceived     customer has not received registration for boat...')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Trending] ([TicketDescription]) VALUES (N'#registrationnoreceived      Customer called and still has not received duplicate registration...')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Trending] ([TicketDescription]) VALUES (N'#callback (111) 111-1111

Agent''s POS is briefly turning on before "going to sleep" and entering sleep mode. Agent claims POS will not stay active for any length of time.')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Trending] ([TicketDescription]) VALUES (N'#Update
Corrected last name and driver''s license number.')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Trending] ([TicketDescription]) VALUES (N'#Update
Update customer''s last name.')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Trending] ([TicketDescription]) VALUES (N'#Update
Update last name, address')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Trending] ([TicketDescription]) VALUES (N'#update - Profile updated. Corrected last name.')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Trending] ([TicketDescription]) VALUES (N'#updateinfo')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Trending] ([TicketDescription]) VALUES (N'#updateinfo')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Trending] ([TicketDescription]) VALUES (N'#updateinfo')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Trending] ([TicketDescription]) VALUES (N'#updateinfo')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Trending] ([TicketDescription]) VALUES (N'#question')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Trending] ([TicketDescription]) VALUES (N'#Update
Update residency status')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Trending] ([TicketDescription]) VALUES (N'#update #SSNdiscrepancy 
John Doe called in claiming this was their SSN, please advise. Please contact John Doe at this number (111-111-2222) when the issue is resolved. He wishes to create an account once the issue is resolved.')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Trending] ([TicketDescription]) VALUES (N'#Notes
Update Customer''s Hunter certificate number')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Trending] ([TicketDescription]) VALUES (N'#update
Updated residency status')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Trending] ([TicketDescription]) VALUES (N'#Update
Changed residency from in-state to out-of-state, likely didn''t update.')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Trending] ([TicketDescription]) VALUES (N'#Update
Updated Customer''s last name')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Trending] ([TicketDescription]) VALUES (N'#updateinfo')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Trending] ([TicketDescription]) VALUES (N'#updateinfo')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Trending] ([TicketDescription]) VALUES (N'#void - Agent called in asking to void a duplicate license sale.')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Trending] ([TicketDescription]) VALUES (N'#Update - updated customer''s last name')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Trending] ([TicketDescription]) VALUES (N'#permissions
Changed agent role from AGENT CLERK to AGENT MANAGER in order to order supplies.')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Trending] ([TicketDescription]) VALUES (N'#registrationreprint customer didn''t receive registration I sent to Twra It for reprint. Told to call if he has not received in 10days ')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Trending] ([TicketDescription]) VALUES (N'#printerissue')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Trending] ([TicketDescription]) VALUES (N'#update - Profile updated. Religious Exempt.')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Trending] ([TicketDescription]) VALUES (N'#reprint   this is 2nd call from customer that they have not received there boat registration...')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Trending] ([TicketDescription]) VALUES (N'#registratedincorrectly  He send in check and info from Clerks office beginning of Dec, ')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Trending] ([TicketDescription]) VALUES (N'#reprint #paperlicense Please reprint this license for the customer, he claims he has not yet received it. ')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Trending] ([TicketDescription]) VALUES (N'#nocostreprint customer did not receive boat regst')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Trending] ([TicketDescription]) VALUES (N'#Update
Updated customer''s address over the phone')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Trending] ([TicketDescription]) VALUES (N'#nochargereprint  ')
GO
```

Just noticed a strange behavior when I ran this same script for a different date range - it's creating #hashtags that do not exist. For example, it is returning Order: 10 times but there is not text within the field for #order:

[image: Non-existant Hashtag]

Sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE #temptable ( [ticketDescription] varchar(max), [RetVal] varchar(max) )
INSERT INTO #temptable
VALUES
( 'DURABLE HARD CARD RETURN-WAS GOING TO CALL TO PICK UP  NO# NUMBER ', 'DURABLE' ), 
( 'Order: 30341143OrderItemId: 30517890License for: NATHAN TIMOTHY SUMNER  Printed on: 10 Apr 2017 06:43:57:857 Shipped to: 7650 KIOWA ST, APT #01 MILLINGTON TN 38053 - 3219', 'Order:' ), 
( 'Order: 30341143OrderItemId: 30517890License for: NATHAN TIMOTHY SUMNER  Printed on: 10 Apr 2017 06:43:57:857 Shipped to: 7650 KIOWA ST, APT #01 MILLINGTON TN 38053 - 3219', '01' ), 
( 'Order: 30346281OrderItemId: 30526511License for: STANLEY R ROWLAND  Printed on: 07 Apr 2017 06:22:23:417 Shipped to: 25 COUNTRY WOOD LN # 601 WALNUT MS 38683 - 5367', 'Order:' ), 
( 'Order: 30347906OrderItemId: 30529325License for: DOUGLAS R EASTRIDGE  Printed on: 07 Apr 2017 09:29:51:643 Shipped to: 7980 HUFFS FERRY RD N # R LOUDON TN 37774 - 5910', 'Order:' ), 
( 'Order: 30361947OrderItemId: 30554547License for: BLAKE R HADDON  Printed on: 07 Apr 2017 14:01:42:637 Shipped to: 146 14TH AVE NW # 146 WINCHESTER TN 37398 - 1079', 'Order:' ), 
( 'Order: 30362075OrderItemId: 30554740License for: KYLE  JACKSON  Printed on: 07 Apr 2017 14:04:23:473 Shipped to: 3765 E ANDREW JOHNSON HWY, APT # A4 MORRISTOWN TN 37814 - 6200', 'Order:' ), 
( 'Order: 30369152OrderItemId: 30565137License for: DANIEL JAMES SOLA  Printed on: 09 Apr 2017 07:08:28:683 Shipped to: 3212 MAYES LOOP RD # 1 PIGEON FORGE TN 37863 - 7721', 'Order:' ), 
( 'Order: 30370097OrderItemId: 30566543License for: JAMES D JOHNSON  Printed on: 09 Apr 2017 11:51:37:170 Shipped to: 230 FRANKLIN RD # 907 FRANKLIN TN 37064 - 2256', 'Order:' ), 
( 'Order: 30372876OrderItemId: 30571083License for: MARCOS  CLAUDIO P POLONIATO  Printed on: 06 Apr 2017 08:15:01:093 Shipped to: 295 WINDING RIVER DR, # J SANDY SPRINGS GA 30350 - 1926', 'Order:' ), 
( 'Order: 30396415OrderItemId: 30604206License for: GARY T GOODMAN  Printed on: 07 Apr 2017 15:11:20:317 Shipped to: 1046 GREENBRIAR RD # RD.423 TALBOTT TN 37877 - 9055', 'Order:' ), 
( 'Order: 30405689OrderItemId: 30617970License for: VANCE K JOHNSON  Printed on: 09 Apr 2017 09:25:48:670 Shipped to: 614 GARRISON HOLLOW RD, LOT # 11 ELIZABETHTON TN 37643 - 4897', 'Order:' )

SELECT * FROM #temptable;

DROP TABLE #temptable
```

---

> **EDIT - To Fix**

```
Select HashTag = '#'+B.RetVal
      ,Cnt      = Count(*)
 From  #temptable A
 Cross Apply [dbo].[udf-Str-Extract]([dbo].[udf-Str-Strip-Control]('#>>> '+A.TicketDescription)+' ','#',' ') B
 Where B.RetVal <> '>>>'
   and B.RetVal Not Like '[0-9][0-9]'
 Group By B.RetVal
 Order By 1
```

Comment: Tip: You may want to read up on [`like`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/like-transact-sql) patterns. Something like `not like '%#[.:''1-9]%'` would tidy things up a bit.

Comment: Thanks - I will look into that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of two function and a CROSS APPLY, the following may help.

The first function will strip all control characters and replace with a space so not to concatinate words like `John{13}{10}Smith` would return as `John Smith`

The second function is a modified parse function to accept two non-like delimiters (begin/end).  In your case a # and space.  **If there are multiple hashtags, it will return multiple records.**

**Example**

```
Select HashTag = '#'+B.RetVal
      ,Cnt      = Count(*)
 From  trending A
 Cross Apply [dbo].[udf-Str-Extract]([dbo].[udf-Str-Strip-Control](A.TicketDescription)+' ','#',' ') B
 Group By B.RetVal
 Order By 1
```

**Returns**

```
HashTag                 Cnt
#callback               1
#nochargereprint        1
#nocostreprint          1
#Notes                  1
#paperlicense           1   ---<< 2nd hashtag in text
#permissions            1
#printerissue           1
#question               1
#registratedincorrectly 1
#registrationnoreceived 1
#registrationnotreceived1
#registrationreprint    1
#reprint                2
#SSNdiscrepancy         1   ---<< 2nd hashtag in text
#Update                 12
#updateinfo             6
#void                   1
```

**If UDFs if Interested**

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udf-Str-Strip-Control](@S varchar(max))
Returns varchar(max)
Begin
    ;with  cte1(N) As (Select 1 From (Values(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) N(N)),
           cte2(C) As (Select Top (32) Char(Row_Number() over (Order By (Select NULL))-1) From cte1 a,cte1 b)
    Select @S = Replace(@S,C,' ')
     From  cte2

    Return LTrim(RTrim(Replace(Replace(Replace(@S,' ','><'),'<>',''),'><',' ')))
End
--Select [dbo].[udf-Str-Strip-Control]('Michael        '+char(13)+char(10)+'LastName')  --Returns: Michael LastName
```

---

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udf-Str-Extract] (@String varchar(max),@Delimiter1 varchar(100),@Delimiter2 varchar(100))
Returns Table 
As
Return (  

with   cte1(N)   As (Select 1 From (Values(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) N(N)),
       cte2(N)   As (Select Top (IsNull(DataLength(@String),0)) Row_Number() over (Order By (Select NULL)) From (Select N=1 From cte1 N1,cte1 N2,cte1 N3,cte1 N4,cte1 N5,cte1 N6) A ),
       cte3(N)   As (Select 1 Union All Select t.N+DataLength(@Delimiter1) From cte2 t Where Substring(@String,t.N,DataLength(@Delimiter1)) = @Delimiter1),
       cte4(N,L) As (Select S.N,IsNull(NullIf(CharIndex(@Delimiter1,@String,s.N),0)-S.N,8000) From cte3 S)

Select RetSeq = Row_Number() over (Order By N)
      ,RetPos = N
      ,RetVal = left(RetVal,charindex(@Delimiter2,RetVal)-1) 
 From  (Select *,RetVal = Substring(@String, N, L) From cte4) A
 Where charindex(@Delimiter2,RetVal)>1
)
/*
Max Length of String 1MM characters

Declare @String varchar(max) = 'Dear [[FirstName]] [[LastName]], ...'
Select * From [dbo].[udf-Str-Extract] (@String,'[[',']]')
*/
```

> **EDIT - May Help with the Visualization**

If you run the query without any aggregegation

```
Select A.*,B.*
 From  trending A
 Cross Apply [dbo].[udf-Str-Extract]([dbo].[udf-Str-Strip-Control](' '+replace(A.TicketDescription,'#','|||#'))+' .','|||',' ') B
 Order By 1
```

**You'll Get**

[image]

Comment: This look promising - can't wait to test it out.  I've got to ask - did you already have these functions or did you just create them?

Comment: @MISNole already had them.  I've found many uses for the Extract function over time.

Comment: @MISNole Full disclosure Inorder to keep the # you will notice that I replace # with |||# and then parse on |||

Comment: May I ask whey you would not simply do something like SELECT ('#' + B.RetVal) as [Hashtag] to keep the ''#" in place?

Comment: @MISNole You can

Comment: @MISNole Cross Apply [dbo].[udf-Str-Extract]([dbo].[udf-Str-Strip-Control](A.TicketDescription)+' ','#',' ') B

Comment: @MISNole in your case, youw would still need to add a space a the end of the string  as illustrated above because you have hashtags with no trailings spaces

Comment: @MISNole updated the CROSS APPLY expression.  Perhaps I was over-thinking it before.

Comment: Thanks John - just tested and I am pleased with the results.  Appreciate it!

Comment: @MISNole Happy it helped

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139912/discussion-between-misnole-and-john-cappelletti).

Comment: @MISNole Just an after thought.  Regarding some of those filters you applied, rather than filtering records going into the query, perhaps it would be safer if filtered by adding a where before the final Group By B.RetVal

Comment: Hey John - not sure exactly what you mean, would you suggest using a CTE or something to get the filtered results and then use the functions? I edited my question to show the final(?) query I used to get the desired results.

Comment: @MISNole no, I just get nervous when data is filtered.  Depending on your filters you may be exclude valid hashtags.   If your comfortable with the resutls, then I think you should be OK

Comment: Hey John - hate to necro a question but i found a strange behavior I was hoping you might help explain.  If it would be better to open a new question, I would be glad to.

Comment: @MISNole What is the issue?

Comment: I posted in the original question but hashtags are being created that don't truly exist

Comment: OK, I see Order and 01 being presented.  The Order is easy to fix by forcing a "dummy" hashtag in the begining of the string like so...  Cross Apply [dbo].[udf-Str-Extract]([dbo].[udf-Str-Strip-Control]('#>>> '+A.TicketDescription)+' ','#',' ') B Where B.RetVal <>'>>>'

Comment: @MISNole If is helps, I added an EDIT - Fix at the bottom of your question

Comment: Awesome - trying to understand exactly what you have done, but this looks good as far as I can tell.

Comment: @MISNole No problem.  Just ping if you need additional help