# Need to match exact string within a varchar column in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, function, t-sql, sql-server-2014

I have a two-part problem in which I am pulling all #hashtags from a column to display which #hashtags were "trending" for a particular time frame to display on an SSRS report. And then I have a sub-report in which the user can click the #hashtag and be taken to all records from the table in which the #hashtag appeared.

To pull the #hashtags from the table, this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43193022/parse-hashtag-comments-from-sql-server-record) showed me how I could accomplish this feat using two functions and a cross apply.

Now I am trying to find an exact match of a text string in a varchar(max) column from a table in SQL Server.  My current query uses a `LIKE` statement:

```
ticketDescription LIKE  '%' + @paramHashtag + '%'
```

This presents a problem because I do have similar #hashtags such as #update and #updateinfo and the `LIKE` statement returns #updateinfo hashtags when I am searching for #update hashtags.

I tried to use `WHERE CONTAINS (ticketDescription, @paramHashtag)` but we do not have full-text enabled and I am not sure that is a possiblility.

If full-text search is not an option, is it possible to look for exact matches on the parameter that will be passed to the query?

Below is sample data from the ticket descriptions:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Trending](
[TicketDescription] [varchar](max) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
```

Values inside the TicketDescription column:

```
#Update  Corrected last name and driver's license number.
#Update  Update customer's last name.
#Update  Update last name, address
#update - Profile updated. Corrected last name.
#updateinfo
#updateinfo
#updateinfo
#updateinfo
#Update  Update residency status
#update #SSNdiscrepancy   John Doe called in claiming this was their SSN, please advise.
#update  Updated residency status
#Update  Changed residency from in-state to out-of-state
#Update  Updated Customer's last name
#updateinfo
#updateinfo
#Update - updated customer's last name
```

Comment: Presumably you want to find the first character that isn't a letter or a number or a hash. e.g. `SELECT SUBSTRING(TicketDescription, 1, PATINDEX('%[^#A-Z0-9]%', TicketDescription) - 1)` If it's always a space after the hash tag, you can use `CHARINDEX(' ', TicketDescription)` instead. Match the parameter on this. This assumes your hash tag is always the first character in your strings. If it isn't, then a slight modification of this is necessary.

Comment: Unfortunately, the first character might not be # and the field might contain multiple #hashtags as well. But the #hashtag should end after the first empty space - so in the sample data above, the 1st record's #hashtag would only be #Update.

Comment: Hm. Then you could search based on whether @param = ticketdescription (e.g. the ticketdescription is the hashtag alone) or `ticketdescription like '%' + @param + ' %'` (note the space before the second percent symbol)... I guess you'd need to include cases where it ends with the parameter but has other text beforehand, e.g. `or right(ticketdescription, len(@param)) = @param`.

Comment: Maybe a silly idea. But why not simple search for the param + a space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example of how you could write a query that should deliver the results you expect (by checking for a match on your hashtag and then a character that isn't a letter or a number - e.g. a space, comma, etc after the hashtag):

```
DECLARE @T TABLE (TicketDescription VARCHAR(MAX));
INSERT @T VALUES 
('junk text #Update  Corrected last name and driver''s license number.'),
('more junk text#Update  Update customer''s last name.'),
('asdfadsf #Update  Update last name, address'),
('#update - Profile updated. Corrected last name.'),
('#updateinfo'),
('#updateinfo'),
('#updateinfo'),
('#updateinfo'),
('#Update  Update residency status'),
('#update #SSNdiscrepancy   John Doe called in claiming this was their SSN, please advise.'),
('#update  Updated residency status'),
('#Update  Changed residency from in-state to out-of-state'),
('asdfasdfadf#Update  Updated Customer''s last name'),
(' asdfadsf #updateinfo'),
('asdf #updateinfo'),
('#Update - updated customer''s last name'),
('#Update'),
('#Update,example with a comma after hashtag');

DECLARE @param VARCHAR(255) = '#update';

SELECT TicketDescription
FROM @T
WHERE TicketDescription LIKE '%' + @param + '[^A-Z0-9]%' -- Hashtag + something that isn't a letter or number.
OR RIGHT(TicketDescription, LEN(@param)) = @param; -- Or it matches the very last part of the given TicketDescription.
```

Comment: Thanks ZLK - I understand what you are doing with '%' + @param + '[^A-Z0-9]% but could you explain what the purpose of Right(Ticket...)? It works and I appreciate that, but I would like to know what the second portion does as well.

Comment: @MISNole The `RIGHT` part is picking up things where the very last part of the TicketDescription is the param. e.g. 'generic text #update' would be picked up. It would also pick up something where the entire TicketDescription is the hash tag (e.g. if your param was "#updateinfo", all the rows with just "#updateinfo" would be picked up). These would not have a space (or anything) after the hash tag, so you need to build a rule for those.

Comment: Thanks ZLK - I appreciate the solution and the explanation.